# Logging true condition of big if(.. || ..) statement

Tags: java, spring

I use Java and I want to determine in logs which statement caused the condition to be true. I have got big if with a lot of ORs. Something like below:

```
if (StringUtils.isTrue(foo.getArg1)
    || StringUtils.isTrue(foo.getArg1)
    || StringUtils.isTrue(foo.getArg2)
    || foo.getArg3.equals("T")
    || foo.getList1.isEmpty()
    || //and so on...) {
       return true; }
```

and i would like to get something like:

```
if (StringUtils.isTrue(foo.getArg1)) {
   log.info("Arg1 made statement true")
          return true;
   }

if (StringUtils.isTrue(foo.getArg2)) {
   log.info("Arg2 made statement true")
          return true;
   }

if (foo.getList1().isEmpty()) {
   log.info("List1 made statement true")
          return true;
   }   //etc...
```

Is there any tricky way to get effect like this in more generic way, without a lot of if statements ?

Comment: (psst... You've spelled "return" wrong in your code. Repeatedly.)

Comment: In your first snippet, just add a one liner log with all the variables and do return as you are  doing already. That should be enough for future troubleshooting purpose, if at all required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a helper logger method that writes a given message to the log if the `boolean` passed to it is `true`:

```
public boolean static logIfTrue (boolean value, String msg) {
    if (value) {
        log.info(msg);
    }
    return value;
}
```

And use it:

```
return logIfTrue(StringUtils.isTrue(foo.getArg1),"Arg1 made statement true") ||
       logIfTrue(StringUtils.isTrue(foo.getArg2),"Arg2 ...") ||
       logIfTrue(foo.getArg3.equals("T"),"...") ||
       logIfTrue(foo.getList1.isEmpty(),"...") ||
       //and so on...;
```